# Не открывается GUI окно WinApi

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

```
#include <Windows.h>// Библиотека для работы с WinApi
    
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);//
    
    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE fparam, HINSTANCE sparam, PSTR agrv, int cmdShow) {//Main функция для WinApi
        //HINSTANCE fparam - хендлер на наше окно(приложение)
        //HINSTANCE sparam - хенделер(уже не используется использовался для 16-битных систем
        //PSTR argv - указатель на строку с переданными командами из консоли
        //int cmdShow - указывает можно ли свернуть окно или нет
    
    // Программы на WinApi состоят из блоков
    // 1 Блок. Блок определения
        char AppName[] = "My first program";//Название окна
        char ClassName[] = "Good luck to me";//Название окна
        HWND hwnd;//Хендлер на главное окно приложения
        MSG msg;//Структура для работы с сообщениями
        WNDCLASSEX wndclass;//Структура описывающая главное окно
    
        wndclass.cbSize = sizeof(wndclass);                        //Задаёт размер окна
        wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;                  //Задаёт стиль окна
        wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;                            //Задаёт функцию которая создаст окно
        wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;                                   //Задаёт дополнительные байты выделяемые для структуры
        wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;                                   //Задаёт дополнительные байты выделяемые для функции создающей окно
        wndclass.hInstance = fparam;                               //Задаёт дескриптор экземпляра(к какой конкретной программе привязать окно,передаётся в Main функцию)
        wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(fparam, IDI_APPLICATION);                   //Задаёт иконку
        wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(fparam, IDC_ARROW);              //Задаёт курсор
        wndclass.hbrBackground = static_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));//Задаёт бэкграунд
        wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;                              //Задаёт название пока неизвестно чего!!!
        wndclass.lpszClassName = AppName;                          //Задаёт название окна
        wndclass.hIcon = NULL;                                     //Задаёт иконку для окна
    
    
        RegisterClassEx(&wndclass);                                //Регистрация нашего класса
        hwnd = CreateWindow(
            AppName,                                               //Название класса
            ClassName,                                             //Название окна
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,                                   //Стиль окна(типо перекрывающий,скрытый и тп)
            CW_USEDEFAULT,                                         //Координата окна по y
            CW_USEDEFAULT,                                         //Координата окна по x
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            NULL,                                                   //Хендлер на класс родителя
            NULL,                                                   //Хендлер на класс меню
            fparam,                                                 //hInstance хендлер на экземпляр нашего приложения
            NULL);                                                  //Сообщение которое может быть передано нашему окну
    
        ShowWindow(hwnd, cmdShow);                                  //Отображает окно hwnd,cmdShow указывает можно ли свернуть окно или нет(передаёт в Main)
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);                                         //Обновляет содержимое окна
    
        while (GetMessage(
            &msg,                                                   //Куда будем записывать полученные сообщения
            hwnd,                                                   //С какого окна брать сообщения,если стоит NULL то брать с любого привязанного к этому потоку
            0,                                                      //Хз
            0)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);                                 //Отправляет в очередь потока приложения MSG(конвертирует виртальные клавиши в символьные)
            DispatchMessage(&msg);                                  //Отправляет сообщение MSG в оконную процедуру(WndProc)
        }
        return msg.wParam;//Если я правильно понял то возврат сообщения при выходе из программы
    }
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {//Опредедение WndProc(которая обрабатывает сообщения полученые из DispatchMessage()
        HDC hdc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        RECT rect;
    
        switch (iMsg) {
        case WM_CREATE:
            MessageBox(hwnd, "First try", "Test succesfull", MB_OK);
            return 0;
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
            DrawText(hdc, "Hello World", -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Не открывается GUI окошко,пример брал с книги Петцольда чуть-чуть модернизировав,компилировал в visual studio2022,без использования unicode'a,в свойствах проекта платформа:Все платформы
Комментарии делал для себя

Comment: ¿И на каком этапе что-то идет не так? Результат вызова большинства функций WinAPI надо проверять

Comment: на этапе выполнения,проект собирается и запускается,висит в диспетчере задач но окошка не видно

Comment: Я имел ввиду на какой строке что-то идет не так? Случаем не тута `wndclass.lpszClassName = AppName;`

Comment: Попробуйте MFC приложение создать с пользовательским интерфейсом (single document). WinApi - это не C++, WinApi - это C.

Comment: У вас опечатка, два раза задаётся поле `wndclass.hIcon`, а поле `wndclass.hIconSm` не задаётся